# How can I build a Perl hash in C code?

Tags: c, perl, hash, xs

I wish to embed a C code in Perl. In this C code I want to read a huge file into memory, make some changes and build a hash (a custom one). I wish to make this hash accessible from my Perl code. Is it possible? How can I reach the goal?

Answer (score 12):

For embedding c in perl, you're looking for XS. Extensive documentation on that can be found in [`perlxs`](http://p3rl.org/perlxs) and [`perlxstut`](http://p3rl.org/perlxstut).

As for building perl data structures from C, you will have to use the parts of the [`perlapi`](http://p3rl.org/perlapi) that deal with hashes. Much documentation on XS already explains various bits of that. The important parts you're looking for are `newHV` and `hv_store`.

Here's a tiny (and completely untested) example of something similar to what you might want to do:

```
SV *
some_func ()
    PREINIT:
        HV *hash;
    CODE:
        hash = newHV();
        hv_stores(hash, "foo", 3, newSViv(42));
        hv_stores(hash, "bar", 3, newSViv(23));
        RETVAL = newRV_noinc((SV *)hash);
    OUTPUT:
        RETVAL
```

That's an XS subroutine called `some_func`, that'll build a hash and return a reference to it to perl space:

```
my $href = some_func();
# $href = { foo => 42, bar => 23 };
```

Answer (score 3):

- See [Internals and C language
  interface](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-internals.html)
- Also have a look at [Inline-C](http://p3rl.org/Inline%3a%3aC) for embedded a C code in perl:The [Inline module](http://p3rl.org/Inline) allows you to
  put source code from other
  programming languages directly
  "inline" in a Perl script or module.
  The code is automatically compiled as
  needed, and then loaded for immediate
  access from Perl.

Also read **[Why should I use Inline to do it?](http://p3rl.org/Inline#Why_Inline?)**

Comment: Oh please stop recommending Inline as the de-facto standard solution to such things. It's a deployment nightmare. Unless the requirement is specifically "I need to do this on my machine and my machine only", Inline translates to problems down the road.

Comment: I'll write XS code when I have to, but when I don't have to, Inline::C is awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to interface between C, Perl, and several other languages.